# Stored procedure with conversion date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes on range of dates:

```
Create Procedure Search_PO
(
@usersID CHAR(10),
@poNo VARCHAR(20), 
@poDateFrom Date, 
@poDateTo Date,
)
As
Begin
    If (@poNo = '') 
    Begin 
    Set @poNo = Null
    End
    If (@poDateFrom = '01/01/0001') 
    Begin
    Set @poDateFrom = Null
    End
    If (@poDateTo = '01/01/0001') 
    Begin
    Set @poDateTo = Null
    End

    Select * From PurchaseOrder p, Users u, Warehouse w 
    Where p.warehouseID = w.warehouseID 
    and w.usersID = u.usersID 
    and u.usersID = @usersID 
    and ((p.poNo like '%' + @poNo + '%') or @poNo Is Null) 
    and (p.poDate >= convert(date, @poDateFrom, 103) Or @poDateFrom Is Null) 
    and (p.poDate <= convert(date, @poDateTo, 103) Or @poDateTo Is Null) 
End
```

This worked normally when I had selected dates where it was below 12(number of months), it throws me back an error of conversion from `varchar` into `date`

I believe this is due to the fact that:

1. Date format in SQL Server is mm/dd/yyyy
2. Date format in Visual Studio is dd/mm/yyyy

I tried using this code as a standalone code to check if my conversion is working:

`select * from PurchaseOrder where poDate <= convert(date,'31/5/2017',103)`

It does work, but when I execute my stored procedure:

`exec Search_PO 'US00000001','','1/1/0001','31/5/2017'`

It returns me the conversion error again. Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Why do you not pass your dates in an unambiguous format such as `yyyymmdd`?

Comment: Don't use old style join syntax! :)

Comment: convert(date,@date,101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently converting your two date paramenters twice - once in the procdeure declaration (implicitly) and once in your select statement (explicitly). Your procedure is failing at the point where the @poDateFrom and @poDateTo parameters are being implicitly cast as date in the stored procedure declaration.  If you're not in control of the format of the date being passed to your procedure you should change the parameter type to varchar.

i.e.

```
ALTER Procedure Search_PO
(
@usersID CHAR(10),
@poNo VARCHAR(20), 
@poDateFrom VARCHAR(10), 
@poDateTo VARCHAR(10),
)
```

This will avoid the implicit conversion and rely only on your explicit conversion (i.e. convert(date, @poDateFrom, 103) ) which, as you've already shown, will work for string value '31/5/2017'

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion, OP should use correct data types and don't rely on any conversions.

Comment: That's true, but in this particular situation, I'm providing an explanation as to why he is seeing a conversion error when he executes the stored procedure as opposed to running the select statement with the string passed directly to the convert function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with explanation, you did it well, I just disagree that strings should be passed as `VARCHAR(10)`, that's it ;)

Comment: The fact that this answers the point of "If you're not in control of the format of the date being passed to your procedure you should change the parameter type to varchar." works for me. I'm really sorry for not giving the details of me having no control over the format of the date passed into my procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in

```
exec Search_PO 'US00000001','','1/1/0001','31/5/2017'
```

You should pass date type parameter on `yyyymmdd` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format, not `dd/mm/yyyy`. 
Change it to:

```
exec Search_PO 'US00000001','','1/01/01','2017/05/31'
```

And you don't need to convert `convert(date, @poDateFrom, 103)`, its type is DATE already.

just

```
and (p.poDate >= @poDateFrom Or @poDateFrom Is Null) 
and (p.poDate <= @poDateTo Or @poDateTo Is Null)
```

Comment: The exec was right, I needed to input the format of the date from Microsoft visual studio which gave me the date format as such

Answer (score 1):

Can you send the dates as text variables and then make the conversion in the stored procedure? You can use SET DATEFORMAT dmy to aling SQL Server and Visual Studio date formats.

With this modification your SP would be like this:

```
Create Procedure Search_PO
(
@usersID CHAR(10),
@poNo VARCHAR(20), 
@poDateFrom_Chr VARCHAR(10), 
@poDateTo_Chr VARCHAR(10),
)
As
Begin

DECLARE @poDateFrom DATE
DECLARE @poDateTo DATE

SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SET @poDateFrom = @poDateFrom_Chr
SET @poDateTo = @poDateTo_Chr
SET DATEFORMAT mdy

If (@poNo = '') 
Begin 
Set @poNo = Null
End
If (@poDateFrom = '01/01/0001') 
Begin
Set @poDateFrom = Null
End
If (@poDateTo = '01/01/0001') 
Begin
Set @poDateTo = Null
End

Select * From PurchaseOrder p, Users u, Warehouse w 
Where p.warehouseID = w.warehouseID 
and w.usersID = u.usersID 
and u.usersID = @usersID 
and ((p.poNo like '%' + @poNo + '%') or @poNo Is Null) 
and (p.poDate >= convert(date, @poDateFrom, 103) Or @poDateFrom Is Null) 
and (p.poDate <= convert(date, @poDateTo, 103) Or @poDateTo Is Null)
```

End

Hope it helps.